# Should I have and async/await on a method if there is an await at the point where it is called?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I have these two Typescript methods:

```
async getCertURL(pol: string): Promise<string> {
  return await Api.getData(this.apiUrl + pol + this.certEndpoint, {timeout: 60000}).then(
    (response) => {
      return response.data.certURL;
    })
    .catch((err) => 
      this.loggingService.logError('Error generating reissue cert forward URL ' + err));
}

async getCert(pol: string): Promise<string> {
return Api.getData(await this.getCertURL(policy), {timeout: 60000}).then(
  (response) => {
    return response.data;
  })
.catch((err) => 
  this.loggingService.logError('Error cert not reissued ' + err));
}
```

I thought if I had an `await` before `await this.getCertURL(policy)` in my `getCert()` I would not require one at `Api.getData()` in `getCertURL` but `getCert()` throws an exception without it.

Am I correct to include it or is there some other way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `await` if the value on the right hand side is a promise and you want the resolved value returned instead of the promise.

Since `getCertURL` is marked as `async`, it will return a promise.

You need the value, so you need `await`.

---

On the other hand, since (inside `getCertURL`) you do nothing with value of the promise returned by `Api.getData().then().catch()` except return it (causing it to be wrapped in a promise) you could omit the `await` and `async` from that function. You'd have clearer code if you replaced the `then()` and `catch()` with `await` and `try {} catch {}` though).